# Function on $[a,b]$ that satisfies a Hölder condition of order $\alpha > 1 $ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, holder-spaces

I want to show that if a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfies a Hölder condition of order $\alpha > 1 $ then it is constant.

The way I think of it is as follows:

$$|f(x) - f(y)| < K|x-y|^\alpha$$

$$\frac{|f(x) - f(y)|} {|x-y]}  < K|x-y|^{\alpha -1}$$

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow x} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|} {|x-y]} \le \lim_{y\rightarrow x}  K|x-y|^{\alpha -1} =0 $$
As the limit is $0$, we can remove the modulus, so we get:

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow x} \frac{f(x) - f(y)} {x-y} = 0$$
So $f$ is derivable and $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$.
Note that the reason we can add the limit $y\rightarrow x$ is because $[a,b]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$.

However, the question gives as a hint using the mean value theorem. I am not sure why one should do that. You would first have to prove that $f$ is derivable in a similar manner to what I did, and then prove that $f$ is constant. Or is there a simpler way to do it and I am missing it?

Also please inform me of any mistakes I did in the proof (if any)/
Thank you!

Comment: The mean value theorem just allows you to conclude that $f'(x) = 0$ on $[a,b]$ means the function is constant there.

Comment: @copper.hat Oh, OK. I just assumed that I well known. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, this is called the $\alpha$-Hölder condition. The Lipschitz condition is only the special case where $\alpha=1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2369044/169085

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/603291/169085

Answer (score 41):

> *Or is there a simpler way to do it (...)?*

This was asked on the site before and requires no differentiability argument nor the mean value theorem, nor anything but the hypothesis, really...

For every $x\ne y$, split the interval $[x,y]$ into $n$ subintervals of length $\frac1n\cdot|x-y|$. The Hölder condition on each interval yields a bound $K\cdot \left(\frac1n\cdot|x-y|\right)^\alpha$. By the triangular inequality used $n-1$ times,
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant n\cdot K\cdot \left(\tfrac1n\cdot|x-y|\right)^\alpha=K\cdot|x-y|^\alpha\cdot \frac1{n^{\alpha-1}}.
$$
Now, consider the limit $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

The mean value theorem is the usual way to show that if $f'$ on an interval, then $f$ is constant on the interval.  If there were two points $a,b$ in the interval for which $f(a)\ne f(b)$, i.e. if $f$ were not constant on the interval, then there would be some point in the interval at which $f'$ is equal to $(f(a)-f(b)/(a-b)\ne0$.

However, I think the stated result can be proved without showing that $f'=0$ everywhere on the interval and without the mean value theorem so that, for example, it's true of functions whose domain is $\mathbb Q$ as well as those whose domain is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I see now. I just assumed that is well known - I did not even use that in my answer. Thank you!

Comment: It is well known, in any reasonable sense of the term, and that is how it is proved.